# A plugin to manage user updates

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am in need of a plugin or any codes, ideas that will make a specific wordpress user have a list of monthly report(payment transactions, account status).

I know it is confusing but what I mean is:
- every month or two, admin will update user savings/credits
- and the user can view his/her current savings/credits
- the user also can view the past report updates

Sample:

Current Savings: #800

Mar 05 - $700
Feb 02 - $400
Jan 02 - $100

When they click one of the past records, they will go to a page with a complete details of the transaction.

NOTE: All payment/transactions are made online. This is just for viewing purpose only. Users cannot edit anything except for their profile.

Can wordpress do this? or I should go with hardcode php? I prefer wordpress because it is convenient to use

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like a custom feature which will require you to build it unless you're payment gateway provides this type of functionality for you.

However, you say that the admin will update some values each month. If you're using custom fields, you can use the custom fields plugin to display the values.